# Ethernet connection not recognized

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I use an ethernet connection for my PC, connected to a router range extender. The connection has worked fine since forever, but recently the ethernet connection has stopped showing up in the list of networks. Here's the result of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
ajw@Beluga:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for ajw: 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlp9s0
       version: 00
       serial: 90:e8:68:7b:3d:ad
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.19.0-46-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.189 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:88 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcd00000-fcd0ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: enp10s0
       version: 15
       serial: 58:11:22:b2:70:c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-46-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:36 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fcc04000-fcc04fff memory:fcc00000-fcc03fff
```

Now I noticed that it says `*-network DISABLED` for the ethernet interface. Any ideas on how to enable it? Other solutions online don't work for me.

Results for `sudo cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`:

```
ajw@Beluga:~$ sudo cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[sudo] password for ajw: 
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

Note that I use Kubuntu 22.04.2.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `sudo cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`

Comment: What happens if you `sudo ifconfig enp10s0 up`

Comment: Doing 'sudo ifconfig enp10s0 up' doesn't do anything. It returns no results and the problem isn't fixed
*EDIT* After doing "sudo ifconfig enp10s0 up," then "sudo lshw -C network" no longer shows the Ethernet interface as disabled, but it still doesn't connect to ethernet, and when I reboot it goes back to saying "Disabled."

Comment: Please add results for `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf; dkms status`

Comment: Please update question with the output of `lspci -nnk | grep Net -A3`.